# Why does smartpy use sp.for/sp.while instead of the default loops provided by python?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, python

So I just started out with smartpy and I am kinda confused about the point of having separate expression for loops. My understanding is that it is may be because it's a part of on-chain computations, but I'm not quite sure.

When using the default for loop expression, I got this error:

Error: 'Expr' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
 for i in range(1, params.op + 1):
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is quite correct.

SmartPy is a Python library, not a Python-inspired language so we use Python everywhere and overload Python's constructions.
This approach is called meta-programming and is extremely important for bigger templates.

Control operators such as `if`, `for`, `while` cannot be overloaded in Python. So we have our own pure-python ones `sp.if_`, `sp.for_`, etc., and use some syntax transformation, called syntactic sugar, to present them nicely to developers.

Some information is here: https://www.smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_control_and_syntactic_sugar

Your first error is in the `range`, you should use `sp.range` since `params.op` is a SmartPy expression, not an integer (as Python is telling you).

Then, you will need to you `sp.for` as SmartPy will tell you because this needs to be executed on-chain, not at compile time.